# Is it possible to create several UserDetailsService spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I found a method that allows me to do what I want but I don't think it's the right method. I have a dto user and a dto admin, when authenticating for email verification with UserDetailService I am unable to verify email for admin because it will verify that in user and return me a reply that the admin does not exist. The only solution I found is with if .
I would like it to browse the userRepository and the adminRepository before returning that the email does not exist. The code below works but it is not the right method. Thank you in advance for your help

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(userRepository.findByEmail(email));
        System.out.println(adminRepository.findByEmail(email) + " admin");

        if (!userRepository.findByEmail(email).isEmpty()) {
            return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                    .orElseThrow(()-> new EntityNotFoundException("Pas d'utilisateur trouvé provenant de cette email"));
        }
        if (!adminRepository.findByEmail(email).isEmpty()) {
            return adminRepository.findByEmail(email)
                    .orElseThrow(()-> new EntityNotFoundException("Pas d'admin trouvé provenant de cette email"));
        }
        return adminRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(()-> new EntityNotFoundException("aucun user trouvé provenant de cette email"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The code below works but it is not the right method"?

Comment: in the case where the user does not exist in userRepository and adminRepository, I return when adminRepository in order to receive an error message and not an empty object. I'm new to springboot, it's a bit complicated to manage security, the same for roads.

Comment: In most cases you should only use one user class/table/service. Why do you need a second kind of user? You should use roles for admin and regular users.

Comment: Thank you @dur because admins will have additional columns. Do you think I should rethink my user and admin tables and make only one?